# Argument not optional vba Countifs

Tags: vba

i have written the vba code you can see below to check whether each row from "E" column has a 'Tie' Value, and if it does, i want to execute countifs to count how many not tie values are between two ties. Anyway, it works on excel, with a syntax like this one: =COUNTIFS($A$2:A6,A6)-1

I wanted to make this work throught vba. So i wrote what you see below, but it keeps giving me "Argument not optional" error, hightlighting Countifs. I can understand that something wrong is there, but i can't understand why. Can you help me?

```
Sub Macro1()

Range("f2").Select

Dim i As Integer
i = 1
Dim var1 As Integer


lastrow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To lastrow
 If Range("E" & i).Value = "Tie" Then
    Range("F" & i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("$A" & "$" & var1 & ":" & "A" & i, "A" & i)) - 1
     var1 = i
 Else
    Range("F" & i).Value = 0
 End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Note: unqualified `Range`, `Rows`, `Columns` or `Name` calls implicitly refer to `ActiveSheet`. This makes `ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` look a bit wrong, and will bite you in the rear end when you try to do the same for another sheet that's not active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Range in error.

Change:

```
Range("$A" & "$" & var1 & ":" & "A" & i, "A" & i)
```

to:

```
Range("$A" & "$" & var1 & ":" & "A" & i), Range("A" & i)
```

So the whole formula would be:

```
Range("F" & i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("$A" & "$" & var1 & ":" & "A" & i), Range("A" & i)) - 1
```

You also need to assign a value to `var1` before the loop, or it will be 0 and there is no row 0:

```
Sub Macro1()

Range("f2").Select

Dim i As Integer
i = 1
Dim var1 As Integer

var1 = 2
With ActiveSheet
    Lastrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To Lastrow
        If .Range("E" & i).Value = "Tie" Then
           .Range("F" & i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.Range("$A" & "$" & var1 & ":" & "A" & i), .Range("A" & i)) - 1
           var1 = i
        Else
           .Range("F" & i).Value = 0
        End If
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```